# Set input and get output to custom tensorflow lite in flutter

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

I am new to tensorflow lite and flutter. I'm a college student and in order to finish my final college project, I have been tasked to implement ml to mobile devices using flutter. The ml model tho made by another student (the model was about giving recommendations from multiple input). And now I don't know how to set the input to the tflite model and get the output. Please, can someone here help me? [Here's the model if you need](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zAc5GZVuL5Jctv1tEIm4IB-Eak_DmRng/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Did you try to use the tflite package ? In their doc they load the model with Tflite.loadModel. Wouldn't be that enough to get you started ?

Comment: Yes and I already read this documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference but when I try to get the input index using .getInputIndex(opName) Should the opName be declared first? Because I keep getting error that says the opName was unidentified

Answer (score 0):

You should start from scratch. Here is a simple example of the [tflite](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite/example) package.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

import 'package:tflite/tflite.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() => runApp(new App());

const String mobile = "MobileNet";
const String ssd = "SSD MobileNet";
const String yolo = "Tiny YOLOv2";
const String deeplab = "DeepLab";
const String posenet = "PoseNet";

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  File _image;
  List _recognitions;
  String _model = mobile;
  double _imageHeight;
  double _imageWidth;
  bool _busy = false;

  Future predictImagePicker() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image == null) return;
    setState(() {
      _busy = true;
    });
    predictImage(image);
  }

  Future predictImage(File image) async {
    if (image == null) return;

    switch (_model) {
      case yolo:
        await yolov2Tiny(image);
        break;
      case ssd:
        await ssdMobileNet(image);
        break;
      case deeplab:
        await segmentMobileNet(image);
        break;
      case posenet:
        await poseNet(image);
        break;
      default:
        await recognizeImage(image);
      // await recognizeImageBinary(image);
    }

    new FileImage(image)
        .resolve(new ImageConfiguration())
        .addListener(ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) {
      setState(() {
        _imageHeight = info.image.height.toDouble();
        _imageWidth = info.image.width.toDouble();
      });
    }));

    setState(() {
      _image = image;
      _busy = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _busy = true;

    loadModel().then((val) {
      setState(() {
        _busy = false;
      });
    });
  }

  Future loadModel() async {
    Tflite.close();
    try {
      String res;
      switch (_model) {
        case yolo:
          res = await Tflite.loadModel(
            model: "assets/yolov2_tiny.tflite",
            labels: "assets/yolov2_tiny.txt",
            // useGpuDelegate: true,
          );
          break;
        case ssd:
          res = await Tflite.loadModel(
            model: "assets/ssd_mobilenet.tflite",
            labels: "assets/ssd_mobilenet.txt",
            // useGpuDelegate: true,
          );
          break;
        case deeplab:
          res = await Tflite.loadModel(
            model: "assets/deeplabv3_257_mv_gpu.tflite",
            labels: "assets/deeplabv3_257_mv_gpu.txt",
            // useGpuDelegate: true,
          );
          break;
        case posenet:
          res = await Tflite.loadModel(
            model: "assets/posenet_mv1_075_float_from_checkpoints.tflite",
            // useGpuDelegate: true,
          );
          break;
        default:
          res = await Tflite.loadModel(
            model: "assets/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224.tflite",
            labels: "assets/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224.txt",
            // useGpuDelegate: true,
          );
      }
      print(res);
    } on PlatformException {
      print('Failed to load model.');
    }
  }

  Uint8List imageToByteListFloat32(
      img.Image image, int inputSize, double mean, double std) {
    var convertedBytes = Float32List(1 * inputSize * inputSize * 3);
    var buffer = Float32List.view(convertedBytes.buffer);
    int pixelIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputSize; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < inputSize; j++) {
        var pixel = image.getPixel(j, i);
        buffer[pixelIndex++] = (img.getRed(pixel) - mean) / std;
        buffer[pixelIndex++] = (img.getGreen(pixel) - mean) / std;
        buffer[pixelIndex++] = (img.getBlue(pixel) - mean) / std;
      }
    }
    return convertedBytes.buffer.asUint8List();
  }

  Uint8List imageToByteListUint8(img.Image image, int inputSize) {
    var convertedBytes = Uint8List(1 * inputSize * inputSize * 3);
    var buffer = Uint8List.view(convertedBytes.buffer);
    int pixelIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputSize; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < inputSize; j++) {
        var pixel = image.getPixel(j, i);
        buffer[pixelIndex++] = img.getRed(pixel);
        buffer[pixelIndex++] = img.getGreen(pixel);
        buffer[pixelIndex++] = img.getBlue(pixel);
      }
    }
    return convertedBytes.buffer.asUint8List();
  }

  Future recognizeImage(File image) async {
    int startTime = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    var recognitions = await Tflite.runModelOnImage(
      path: image.path,
      numResults: 6,
      threshold: 0.05,
      imageMean: 127.5,
      imageStd: 127.5,
    );
    setState(() {
      _recognitions = recognitions;
    });
    int endTime = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    print("Inference took ${endTime - startTime}ms");
  }

  Future recognizeImageBinary(File image) async {
    int startTime = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    var imageBytes = (await rootBundle.load(image.path)).buffer;
    img.Image oriImage = img.decodeJpg(imageBytes.asUint8List());
    img.Image resizedImage = img.copyResize(oriImage, height: 224, width: 224);
    var recognitions = await Tflite.runModelOnBinary(
      binary: imageToByteListFloat32(resizedImage, 224, 127.5, 127.5),
      numResults: 6,
      threshold: 0.05,
    );
    setState(() {
      _recognitions = recognitions;
    });
    int endTime = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    print("Inference took ${endTime - startTime}ms");
  }

  Future yolov2Tiny(File image) async {
    int startTime = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    var recognitions = await Tflite.detectObjectOnImage(
      path: image.path,
      model: "YOLO",
      threshold: 0.3,
      imageMean: 0.0,
      imageStd: 255.0,
      numResultsPerClass: 1,
    );
    // var imageBytes = (await rootBundle.load(image.path)).buffer;
    // img.Image oriImage = img.decodeJpg(imageBytes.asUint8List());
    // img.Image resizedImage = img.copyResize(oriImage, 416, 416);
    // var recognitions = await Tflite.detectObjectOnBinary(
    //   binary: imageToByteListFloat32(resizedImage, 416, 0.0, 255.0),
    //   model: "YOLO",
    //   threshold: 0.3,
    //   numResultsPerClass: 1,
    // );
    setState(() {
      _recognitions = recognitions;
    });
    int endTime = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    print("Inference took ${endTime - startTime}ms");
  }

  Future ssdMobileNet(File image) async {
    int startTime = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    var recognitions = await Tflite.detectObjectOnImage(
      path: image.path,
      numResultsPerClass: 1,
    );
    // var imageBytes = (await rootBundle.load(image.path)).buffer;
    // img.Image oriImage = img.decodeJpg(imageBytes.asUint8List());
    // img.Image resizedImage = img.copyResize(oriImage, 300, 300);
    // var recognitions = await Tflite.detectObjectOnBinary(
    //   binary: imageToByteListUint8(resizedImage, 300),
    //   numResultsPerClass: 1,
    // );
    setState(() {
      _recognitions = recognitions;
    });
    int endTime = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    print("Inference took ${endTime - startTime}ms");
  }

  Future segmentMobileNet(File image) async {
    int startTime = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    var recognitions = await Tflite.runSegmentationOnImage(
      path: image.path,
      imageMean: 127.5,
      imageStd: 127.5,
    );

    setState(() {
      _recognitions = recognitions;
    });
    int endTime = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    print("Inference took ${endTime - startTime}");
  }

  Future poseNet(File image) async {
    int startTime = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    var recognitions = await Tflite.runPoseNetOnImage(
      path: image.path,
      numResults: 2,
    );

    print(recognitions);

    setState(() {
      _recognitions = recognitions;
    });
    int endTime = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    print("Inference took ${endTime - startTime}ms");
  }

  onSelect(model) async {
    setState(() {
      _busy = true;
      _model = model;
      _recognitions = null;
    });
    await loadModel();

    if (_image != null)
      predictImage(_image);
    else
      setState(() {
        _busy = false;
      });
  }

  List<Widget> renderBoxes(Size screen) {
    if (_recognitions == null) return [];
    if (_imageHeight == null || _imageWidth == null) return [];

    double factorX = screen.width;
    double factorY = _imageHeight / _imageWidth * screen.width;
    Color blue = Color.fromRGBO(37, 213, 253, 1.0);
    return _recognitions.map((re) {
      return Positioned(
        left: re["rect"]["x"] * factorX,
        top: re["rect"]["y"] * factorY,
        width: re["rect"]["w"] * factorX,
        height: re["rect"]["h"] * factorY,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
            border: Border.all(
              color: blue,
              width: 2,
            ),
          ),
          child: Text(
            "${re["detectedClass"]} ${(re["confidenceInClass"] * 100).toStringAsFixed(0)}%",
            style: TextStyle(
              background: Paint()..color = blue,
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 12.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  List<Widget> renderKeypoints(Size screen) {
    if (_recognitions == null) return [];
    if (_imageHeight == null || _imageWidth == null) return [];

    double factorX = screen.width;
    double factorY = _imageHeight / _imageWidth * screen.width;

    var lists = <Widget>[];
    _recognitions.forEach((re) {
      var color = Color((Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt() << 0)
          .withOpacity(1.0);
      var list = re["keypoints"].values.map<Widget>((k) {
        return Positioned(
          left: k["x"] * factorX - 6,
          top: k["y"] * factorY - 6,
          width: 100,
          height: 12,
          child: Text(
            "● ${k["part"]}",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: color,
              fontSize: 12.0,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }).toList();

      lists..addAll(list);
    });

    return lists;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    List<Widget> stackChildren = [];

    if (_model == deeplab && _recognitions != null) {
      stackChildren.add(Positioned(
        top: 0.0,
        left: 0.0,
        width: size.width,
        child: _image == null
            ? Text('No image selected.')
            : Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        image: MemoryImage(_recognitions),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                child: Opacity(opacity: 0.3, child: Image.file(_image))),
      ));
    } else {
      stackChildren.add(Positioned(
        top: 0.0,
        left: 0.0,
        width: size.width,
        child: _image == null ? Text('No image selected.') : Image.file(_image),
      ));
    }

    if (_model == mobile) {
      stackChildren.add(Center(
        child: Column(
          children: _recognitions != null
              ? _recognitions.map((res) {
                  return Text(
                    "${res["index"]} - ${res["label"]}: ${res["confidence"].toStringAsFixed(3)}",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      background: Paint()..color = Colors.white,
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList()
              : [],
        ),
      ));
    } else if (_model == ssd || _model == yolo) {
      stackChildren.addAll(renderBoxes(size));
    } else if (_model == posenet) {
      stackChildren.addAll(renderKeypoints(size));
    }

    if (_busy) {
      stackChildren.add(const Opacity(
        child: ModalBarrier(dismissible: false, color: Colors.grey),
        opacity: 0.3,
      ));
      stackChildren.add(const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('tflite example app'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          PopupMenuButton<String>(
            onSelected: onSelect,
            itemBuilder: (context) {
              List<PopupMenuEntry<String>> menuEntries = [
                const PopupMenuItem<String>(
                  child: Text(mobile),
                  value: mobile,
                ),
                const PopupMenuItem<String>(
                  child: Text(ssd),
                  value: ssd,
                ),
                const PopupMenuItem<String>(
                  child: Text(yolo),
                  value: yolo,
                ),
                const PopupMenuItem<String>(
                  child: Text(deeplab),
                  value: deeplab,
                ),
                const PopupMenuItem<String>(
                  child: Text(posenet),
                  value: posenet,
                )
              ];
              return menuEntries;
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: stackChildren,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: predictImagePicker,
        tooltip: 'Pick Image',
        child: Icon(Icons.image),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can read more from [here](https://itnext.io/working-with-tensorflow-lite-in-flutter-f00d733a09c3).

Comment: Um sorry my bad, but the model was like giving recommendations. The model was outputting some recommendations and need some multiple inputs like strings and numbers.